# How do I get my cursor to jump to the last character on a line?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper, code-formatting

This problem has not always been around, and I can find no option in VS or ReSharper to correct it, but when I use the mouse to place the cursor on a shortish line of code, and I place the cursor near the end of the line, in whitespace, it stays there, instead of jumping back to the last character on the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can uncheck the option *Texteditor -> All Languages -> General -> Enable virtual space* in Visual Studio. This way your cursor will always be placed at the last character of a line when you click anywhere in the whitespace area at the end of a line.

Note however if your line ends with whitespaces *you actually typed in*, it will place the cursor after the last actual whitespace of that line. Use **Ctrl + Left Arrow** to jump to the last actual character of that line.

You can use **Alt + Backspace** to quickly delete all whitespaces at the end of a line.