# problem with IDEs which when you click on a line in editor, the cursor does't go to the last written character

Tags: ide, editor, iar, mikroc

I've seen a few IDEs like `IAR embedded workbench` or `MikroC-pro from mikroelektronika`, that when you click on a line, the cursor doesn't go to the last character. instead, it just sits right there on the white space. the problem seems to be same as this one :

[How do I get my cursor to jump to the last character on a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36567778/how-do-i-get-my-cursor-to-jump-to-the-last-character-on-a-line)

but I can't find similar options or any other relevant option to do that. I've included a few screenshots from MikroC editor options dialog:

[image]

and after **open options dialog** under advanced editor options:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IAR Embedded Workbench IDE, select `Tools > Options...` in top menu. This opens *IDE Options* dialog. Select `Editor` node on the tree on the left side of the dialog, then uncheck `Enable virtual space` checkbox. Finally click OK to apply changes.

On MikroC, disable `Scroll past end of line` checkbox on *Editor options* dialog *Options* tab.

Comment: it worked for IAR thanx. is there any relevant item in the editor options for MikroC pro with that screenshots above ?

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad I don't know about MikroC, but have you tried disabling `Scroll past end of line` shown in your screenshot?

Comment: yes, it worked! if you mind updating the answer to be helpful for others it'll be good.